# nodejs execFile not returning result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call an exe file using childprocess.execFile. It is not throwing any errors but also not returning any result, which is printed when I run the exe directly from command line. Code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var result = '';
var child = exec('file.exe', ['-arg1'], function(err, d) {  
    console.log('err: '+err)
    console.log(d.toString());                       
});
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    result += data;
});
child.on('close', function() {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Output: err: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code and also check path of file

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('file.exe', ['-arg1'], null, (error, data) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    console.log(data);
});
/....code..../
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I've tried your code and still nothing is printed, however when I changed the last line, console.log(data) to console.log('result: ' + data), even the 'result: ' part is not printed so the console.log is not being called at all for some reason

Comment: @AbhiDolya - As per documentation - https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback fourth parameter is callback function and not third, you have third parameter as call back. I have edited my code.

Comment: i've added the null as the third argument. And I've put a console.log('done') just before console.log('result: ' + data). The 'done' is printed but the 'result: ' is not printed, nor is the data :S

Comment: I guess the issue is with console.log. I've got the output to save to a file.